# Switching from Nvidia proprietary driver to Nouveau driver for Nvidia card on Debian wheezy

Tags: video, nvidia, debian, nouveau

I am running Debian wheezy. I have the following Nvidia graphics card installed: GeForce 7300 SE/7200 GS.

I am currently using the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers. I have the following packages installed containing `nvidia` in their names.

```
ii  glx-alternative-nvidia                 0.2.2                    amd64                    allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  libgl1-nvidia-alternatives             304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    transition libGL.so* diversions to glx-alternative-nvidia
ii  libgl1-nvidia-glx:amd64                304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    NVIDIA binary OpenGL libraries
ii  libglx-nvidia-alternatives             304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    transition libgl.so diversions to glx-alternative-nvidia
ii  libxvmcnvidia1:amd64                   304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    NVIDIA binary XvMC library
ii  nvidia-alternative                     304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  nvidia-glx                             304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    NVIDIA metapackage
ii  nvidia-installer-cleanup               20120630+3               amd64                    Cleanup after driver installation with the nvidia-installer
ii  nvidia-kernel-3.2.0-4-amd64            304.88-1+deb7u1+3.2.46-1 amd64                    NVIDIA binary kernel module for Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
ii  nvidia-kernel-common                   20120630+3               amd64                    NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-kernel-dkms                     304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    NVIDIA binary kernel module DKMS source
ii  nvidia-kernel-source                   304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    NVIDIA binary kernel module source
ii  nvidia-settings                        304.88-1                 amd64                    Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-support                         20120630+3               amd64                    NVIDIA binary graphics driver support files
ii  nvidia-vdpau-driver:amd64              304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    NVIDIA vdpau driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia              304.88-1+deb7u1          amd64                    NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

I also have the following `xorg.conf` file.

```
Section "Device"
Identifier     "nVidia Corporation G70 [GeForce 7300 GS]"
Driver         "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "My Screens"
Option         "TwinView" "1"
Option         "MetaModes" "1280x1024, 1920x1200"
EndSection
```

I want to try using the nouveau driver instead, but without removing the nvidia proprietary drivers. What steps do I need to take to switch to the nouveau driver?

UPDATE: My attempt to switch to Nouveau failed - the X log appears
[here](http://pastebin.com/M8WesePu).

Comment: The arch linux nvidia wiki page has a section discussing automatic switching between the two and includes to short shell scripts to accomplish the task here. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Switching_between_NVIDIA_and_nouveau_drivers

Comment: The above is not offered as an answer primarily because i do not know how applicable it is to Debian. I do note that noveau is added as a module for mkinitcpio - meaning nouveau is included in initramfs.

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply backup your current filesystem and blithely experiment to your heart's content. If you use device mapper or btrfs this can be instantly handled with snapshotting. Then you just restore as often as you need to until youve got it working.

Comment: http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/TroubleShooting/#igettheeqoverflowingerror ... appears the nouveau driver doesn't work on your hardware. Jessie's nouveau is a fair bit newer, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a backport.